# Firebase UI not working with google signIn : updateCurrentUser failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm adding FirebaseUI to my react website with the basic code from this github repo with a local state :
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react.
When I'm trying to connect to firebase the popup window comes I and shows me my google accounts. Except when the window disapears my App is unable to connect to my google account and shows me this.
[image]

And my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { config } from '../../Components/Firebase/firebase';

firebase.initializeApp(config)

class Orders extends React.Component {

  // The component's Local state.
  state = {
    isSignedIn: false // Local signed-in state.
  };

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  uiConfig = {
    // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false
    }
  };

  // Listen to the Firebase Auth state and set the local state.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        (user) => this.setState({isSignedIn: !!user})
    );
  }
  
  // Make sure we un-register Firebase observers when the component unmounts.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <p>Please sign-in:</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <p>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}! You are now signed-in!</p>
        <a onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas what could cause that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you post your code related to the authentication ?

Comment: Yes I just did it

Comment: The error message is complaining about a call to updateCurrentUser, but your code shows no such call.  Please edit the question to identify specifically which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: It's a template code provided by the github of firebaseui for react. In the github there isn't any mention to this call neither...

Comment: Hey @pledesch. It looks like firebaseui-web-react actually depends on firebaseui-web. I found this github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/536. There are a few suggestions in there from other developers that you can try. In summary, it seems to have to do with loading the sdk twice. Perhaps once through npm and the other through a script tag. Removing one might help solve the issue for you. Hope this helps.